# Unrecognized Spring cache annotations when self-invoking a method from within the same bean

Tags: spring-cache

Dear Spring Cache project community,

currently I'm implementing an Apache CXF-based Spring (version 4.1.5) web service endpoint using the contract 1st approach. Here, I observe when annotating a public method within my web service class, the Spring cache annotations "@Cachable" are ignored each time I call this method in a self-invoked way within the same bean. This could be proven when taking a look on the cache repository (via JMX) of the underlying cache provider (here: EhCache). There, no filling of the cache takes place.

After taking a look on the current Spring documentation below
[Enable caching annotations](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotation-enable) and
[The dispatcher servlet](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet) I assume it might be due to the fact that:

> `<cache:annotation-driven/>` only looks for @Cacheable/@CachePut/@CacheEvict/@Caching on beans in the same application context it is defined in. This means that, if you put  in a WebApplicationContext for a DispatcherServlet, it only checks for beans in your controllers, and not your services. See Section 17.2, “The DispatcherServlet” for more information.

Currently, an Apache CXF "CXFServlet" registered within the "web.xml" deployment descriptor is starting a Spring WebApplicationContext using the "cxf-servlet.xml" Spring application context file by default. There, the `<cache:annotation-driven/>` is located.

Or is it maybe due to the fact that I'm calling the @Cacheable annotated method from within the same Spring bean so that the generated Spring proxy is bypassed? Details can be found in the "Proxy mechanisms" chapter (9.6) of the Spring documentation as well.

But I do not know how to change the behaviour so that my method results are being cached. Do you have any ideas? Or are my assumptions I posted above incorrect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dear Spring community,

I found the important comment within the [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#cache-annotations-cacheable-key) that approves my assumption:

> In proxy mode (which is the default), only external method calls coming in through the proxy are intercepted. This means that self-invocation, in effect, a method within the target object calling another method of the target object, will not lead to an actual caching at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with @Cacheable - considering using the aspectj mode in this case. Also, the proxy must be fully initialized to provide the expected behaviour so you should not rely on this feature in your initialization code, i.e. @PostConstruct.

In consequence this means refactoring the code when relying on Spring AOP and its proxy mode technique or switching the mode from "proxy" to "aspectj" `<cache:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"/>`. This allows using self-invoking methods within the same class as AOP does static respectively dynamic weaving and so manipulates the byte code directly.